# How am I able to let my 2 PC over internet see one another as if they are on the same network segment?

Tags: vpn, nat, vlan

How am I able to let my 2 PC over internet see one another as if they are on the same network segment?

Comment: Off to Superuser.com - this is not a business environment question.

Answer (score 1):

With a [VPN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

You have tons of options to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

With a VPN. Usually in advanced routers you can setup one, this means both routers in both ends must support it.

If both ends have a computer you might leave them switched on, use it as a server and setup Openvpn there. the router then will just NAT the openvpn port to the server and from the server you will have your LAN plugged to your SWITCH who will connect your pc.

An application called teamviewer might help you too, there's a vpn option but I've never used

Answer (score 1):

1) On 1st PC setup OpenVPN(or any other VNP server) server.

2) On the router connected to the 1st computer, setup port forward or DMZ

3) On 2nd PC setup connection to 1st PC